# What is a self-contained mobile app?

Tags: mobile, self-contained

I was asked to create a self-contained mobile (android) app.

What do it means by **self-contained** app ??

Can it connect to a remote server/ database ?
Can it use an internal SqlLite database on mobile?

Are there any other restrictions/ conditions that apply to a self-contained app ?

Comment: Who gave you this project?  Is this for a class or as a demo?  Usually self-contained means just that - it contains everything inside itself.  Thus, no external dependencies (like a database).

Comment: @BiggsTRC the project is for a local app contest. Okay so should not even use a database present in the mobile (not over network)? In that case I may have to use files(xml or other) to store some sample data of the app. I'm I correct so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A self contained application requires absolutely no network connections or external dependancies in order to meet it's functional requirements.